# implement a tree class from ground in java

Tags: java, tree, nodes, treenode

I am implementing a tree class from scratch, I have data fields and constructor like below: 
    public class TreeNode implements Node{
    int data;
    TreeNode child;
    TreeNode parent;
    String name;
    Boolean visited;

```
public TreeNode(int data){
    this.data = data;
    child = null;
    parent = null;
    name = null;
    visited = false;
}
```

one of the method I need to implement is getChildren(Node n), which returns a list that contains all children of Node n. 
I have no idea about how to find all children of nodes. 
thank you for your help!

```
public List<Node> getChildren() {
    List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();
    while(!children.contains(this.child)){
    children.add(this.child);}
    return children;
}
```

Comment: Read books on tree insertion (e.g Sedgewick Algorithms in Java) , without studying these technics, it is unlikely that you correctly reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your ArrayList outside of the class declaration so that you may use it in all of your methods. You would then need some way to add a new child node to your current node, which `addChild(Treenode child)` takes care of.

```
public class TreeNode {

    private ArrayList<TreeNode> children; 

    public TreeNode(int data){
        children = new ArrayList<>();        
    }

    public void addChild(TreeNode child){
        children.add(child);
    }

    public ArrayList<TreeNode> getChildren(){        
        return children;
    } 
}
```

Comment: If this answered your question, would you kindly accept it? Thanks.